# Camel-Jetty HTTP/2 support

Tags: apache-camel, jetty

I've seen that Jetty now supports HTTP/2. Spent some time researching and can't see a way of implementing this in Apache Camel-Jetty. Any idea whether this is something that Camel will need to implement? Or is it configurable using their RestConfigurationDefinition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need to do some extra work to enable the HTTP/2 feature. Camel-Jetty Components has two parts, one is Consumer (Jetty Server) and the other is Producer (Jetty Client). If you want to enable the HTTP/2 feature, you need to make sure the Http module is loaded by modifying some code. I don't think you can do it by doing some configuration with the RestConfigurationDefinition.

Please send a feature request by creating a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL) for it.

Comment: I also need camel-jetty support http2, could you please tell me where to modify some code? thanks and Rgds